# Remove programmatically siblings views

Tags: android

I am using a FlowLayout which is like a horizontal linear layout , but when it reaches the end of the line elements within the layout continue on the next line .

https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

I need to programmatically delete the views on the right of a particular view within the FlowLayout , the views ( textviews )  are created  programmatically :

For example (if each letter were a view )
AAAAXBBB

I want to delete the views to the right of the view X.

How I can remove programmatically the siblings to the right of the X view ?

If I keep them all in an array of views , I can do it , but it can be done without having to store the views in an array of views ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
int children= layout.getChildCount();
for(int i=children-1; i>=0; i--) {
    View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
    if(child == viewX) {
        break;
    }
    layout.removeViewAt(i);

}
```

This will loop over the children of the layout from the end to the beginning, removing each one until it finds the view X